# How to add a node to an XML structure using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a complex structure which contains a list ofthe following form

```
complex tree here
...
<ns3:timestampList xmlns="myNameSpace">
            <timestampInfo>
                    <timestampID>START</timestampID>
                    <timestamp>2012-02-25T00:30:18.705+01:00</timestamp>                        
            </timestampInfo>
            <timestampInfo>
                    <timestampID>END</timestampID>
                    <timestamp>2012-02-25T00:30:23.675+01:00</timestamp>
            </timestampInfo>
            <timestampInfo>
                    <timestampID>RE_START</timestampID>
                    <timestamp>2012-02-25T00:30:18.705+01:00</timestamp>
            </timestampInfo>
</ns3:timestampList>
```

I would like to retain the whole try and only add a new `timestampinfo` block.
I know that I could traverse the tree and add to the output all the nodes using `copy-of` but I wonder if there is no better and elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:param name="new-ts">
  <timestampInfo xmlns="myNameSpace">
    ...
  </timestampInfo>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns3:timestampList">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$new-ts"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

might suffice to give you an idea although with different namespaces used but not completely given in your sample my code is also not complete.